# Logic App - Cannot find (NotFound) queue with slashes in the name

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to have a Service Bus queue trigger my flow in Logic App.
I have used service Bus queue trigger and passed the queue name that is 'test/test' - I am trying to have it work for queues with slashes in the name.
It does not work, I receive the error type NotFound and the input data of the error reads:

```
...
    "method": "get",
    "path": "/test%2Ftest/messages/head",
    "queries": {
        "queueType": "Main"
    }
...
```

I have seen on the portal that / character is changed to ~ and tried to do this as well, both in the designer and in code, still no luck.

```
does not help
"path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('test/test')}/messages/head",
nor
"path": "/test/test/messages/head",
nor
"path": "test/test/messages/head",
nor
"path": "/test~test/messages/head",
nor
"path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('test~test')}/messages/head",
```

I can't influence the rest of the SB infrastructure and move to nicely named queues, it is just a place I wanted to hook into and suck the data out.
Please help if you see a solution.

**Edit**:

I think there is some inconsistency in working of the Designer and the logic behind it, because when I use a connection string with Manage policy, the Designed allows to browse the queues and pick one that is test/test.
It gets configured by following the rules of the Designer but cannot be used (bug?). The tries in the Code view are just to find a workaround for the issue.

Comment: Have you tried: 
"path": "/@{encodeURIComponent('test~test')}/messages/head",

Comment: This also did not help. I edited the question to add this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with my Azure logic app when I try to send a message to service bus queue named `test/test`. As you said, it enables us to choose that queue, but **NotFound** error is returned after running the Azure logic app.

Sending message to another queue which name does not contain `/`, the logic app can work fine, but you seems not want to use nicely named queues.

You could give a feedback on [Logic Apps UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps) for this issue, the Logic Apps Team might help solve the issue.

***Screenshots of my test:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help. I sent a post to User Voice as you proposed. Let's see if this gets attention. I marked your help as answered but would love to have this also fully solved :-)

Comment: This is now SOLVED with Logic Apps :)